# Android app - Do I have to translate app store listing as well?

Tags: android, localization, translate

I have an app with 20 different in app strings for 20 different languages, my question is, when I upload it to google play, do I have to translate the store listing to these 20 languges as well or I can have in shown only in english store listing?

Hope I'm clear,
Thanks!
Dvir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for sure you can have it in english only,
just set english as main (and only) language there, so don't add others.
Then everyone can only see the english description.

but for sure it would be nice for the non-english people
to have it in their language aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

In-app strings for different languages are part of the app, and store listing content (short description, long description, and title) is not part of the app. 
Both are independent to each other, and both are important. In-app strings for different languages help users access the app in their languages, and thus improves the retention. Store listing content in different languages help users discover the app in an easy manner (How? Default store listing translations are not as good as manual translations for the store listing content).

In short, you do not have to have store listing in multiple languages, but it is strongly recommended to have listing in multi language when you already have in-app multi language support.